# Implications from definition of discrete markov chains

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, conditional-probability

Discrete markov chains can be defined by their propterty $$\mathbb{P}(X_n = z_n | X_{n-1}=z_{n-1}, ..., X_0 = z_0) = \mathbb{P}(X_n = z_n | X_{n-1}=z_{n-1}).$$

Intuitively it should also hold for example: $$\mathbb{P}(X_n = z_n | X_{n-1}=z_{n-1}, ..., X_{n-k} = z_{n-k}) = \mathbb{P}(X_n = z_n | X_{n-1}=z_{n-1}).$$

But how can I prove this? More generally, can we say something for an expression like $\mathbb{P}((X_{n+r}, ..., X_n)\in A| (X_{n-1}, ..., X_{0})\in B)$?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I will switch back and forth on notation for events. For example, these two expressions are the same:
\begin{equation}
\{X = z\}~~~\textrm{is the event}~~~\{\omega\in\Omega : X(\omega) = z\}.
\end{equation}

---

Let $S$ be the space in which all the $X_i$ take values. Then
\begin{equation}
\left\{\omega\in\Omega : X_i(\omega) \in S\right\} = \Omega,
\end{equation}
the entire sample space. This ensures that if $A$ is an event, then $A\cap\{X_i\in S\} = A$.

Let $A$ be the event
\begin{equation}
A = \left\{\omega\in\Omega : X_{n-1}(\omega) = z_{n-1},\ldots,X_{n-k}(\omega)=z_{n-k}\right\}.
\end{equation}
Then
\begin{eqnarray}
&& \mathsf{P}(X_n = z_n\mid X_{n-1} = z_{n-1},\ldots,X_{n-k}=z_{n-k})\\
&=& \mathsf{P}(X_n = z_n\mid A)\\
&=&
\mathsf{P}(X_n = z_n\mid A\cap \{X_{n-k-1}\in S\})\\
&=&
\mathsf{P}(X_n = z_n\mid A\cap \{X_{n-k-1}\in S\}\cap \{X_{n-k-2}\in S\})\\
&\vdots&\\
&=&
\mathsf{P}(X_n = z_n\mid A\cap \{X_{n-k-1}\in S\}\cap\cdots\cap \{X_0\in S\}).
\end{eqnarray}

We need to introduce more notation to keep equations on single lines. Let
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{X} = (X_{n-k-1},\ldots,X_0).
\end{equation}
Then the probability in the final line can be expressed as
\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{\mathbf{z}\in S^{n-k}}\mathsf{P}(X_n=z_n\mid A\cap\underbrace{\{\mathbf{X} \in S^{n-k}}_{\Omega}\}).
\end{eqnarray}

We decompose $\mathsf{P}(X_n=z_n\mid A\cap\{\mathbf{X}\in S^{n-k}\})$ as follows. Note that $\{\mathbf{X}\in S^{n-k}\} = \Omega$, so $A\cap\{\mathbf{X}\in S^{n-k}\} = A$.
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\mathsf{P}(X_n=z_n\mid A\cap\{\mathbf{X}\in S^{n-k}\})\\
&=& \mathsf{P}\left(X_n=z_n\mid A\cap\left(\cup_{\mathbf{z}\in S^{n-k}}\{\mathbf{X} = \mathbf{z}\}\right)\right)\\
&=& \mathsf{P}\left(X_n=z_n\mid \cup_{\mathbf{z}\in S^{n-k}}A\cap\{\mathbf{X} = \mathbf{z}\}\right)
\end{eqnarray}

We now apply Bayes's Formula to the conditional probability.
\begin{eqnarray}
&& \mathsf{P}\left(X_n=z_n\mid \cup_{\mathbf{z}\in S^{n-k}}A\cap\{\mathbf{X} = \mathbf{z}\}\right)\\
&=& \frac{\mathsf{P}\left(\{X_n=z_n\}\cap\left(\cup_{\mathbf{z}\in S^{n-k}}A\cap\{\mathbf{X} = \mathbf{z}\}\right)\right)}{\mathsf{P}\left(\cup_{\mathbf{z}\in S^{n-k}}A\cap\{\mathbf{X} = \mathbf{z}\}\right)}\\
&=& \frac{\mathsf{P}\left(\cup_{\mathbf{z}\in S^{n-k}}\{X_n=z_n\}\cap A\cap\{\mathbf{X} = \mathbf{z}\}\right)}{\mathsf{P}\left(\cup_{\mathbf{z}\in S^{n-k}}A\cap\{\mathbf{X} = \mathbf{z}\}\right)}
\end{eqnarray}

For distinct $\mathbf{z}$, the events in the union are disjoint. The probability of the union of disjoint events is the sum of the individual probabilities.

\begin{eqnarray}
&& \mathsf{P}\left(\cup_{\mathbf{z}\in S^{n-k}}\{X_n=z_n\}\cap A\cap\{\mathbf{X} = \mathbf{z}\}\right)\\
&=& \sum_{\mathbf{z}\in S^{n-k}}\mathsf{P}\left(\{X_n=z_n\}\cap A\cap\{\mathbf{X} = \mathbf{z}\}\right)
\end{eqnarray}

We now apply Bayes's Formula to the inidvidual probabilities:
\begin{eqnarray}
&& \mathsf{P}\left(\{X_n=z_n\}\cap A\cap\{\mathbf{X} = \mathbf{z}\}\right)\\
&=& \mathsf{P}\left(X_n=z_n\mid A\cap\{\mathbf{X} = \mathbf{z}\}\right)\mathsf{P}\left(A\cap\{\mathbf{X} = \mathbf{z}\}\right)
\end{eqnarray}
In the event $A\cap\{\mathbf{X} = \mathbf{z}\}$, each $X_i$ from $i=0$ to $i=n-1$ has a specific value. By the Markov property, then,
\begin{eqnarray}
&& \mathsf{P}\left(X_n=z_n\mid A\cap\{\mathbf{X} = \mathbf{z}\}\right)\\
&=& \mathsf{P}\left(X_n=z_n\mid X_{n-1}=z_{n-1}\right).
\end{eqnarray}

When we combine these results, we have
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\mathsf{P}(X_n=z_n\mid A\cap\{\mathbf{X}\in S^{n-k}\})\\
&=& \frac{\sum_{\mathbf{z}\in S^{n-k}}\mathsf{P}\left(X_n=z_n\mid X_{n-1}=z_{n-1}\right)\mathsf{P}\left(A\cap\{\mathbf{X} = \mathbf{z}\}\right)}{\mathsf{P}\left(\cup_{\mathbf{z}\in S^{n-k}}A\cap\{\mathbf{X} = \mathbf{z}\}\right)}.
\end{eqnarray}

Since $\mathsf{P}\left(X_n=z_n\mid X_{n-1}=z_{n-1}\right)$ has no dependence on $\mathbf{z}$ (the values of $X_{n-k-1},\ldots,X_0$), we can "bring it outside" of the sum:
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\mathsf{P}(X_n=z_n\mid A\cap\{\mathbf{X}\in S^{n-k}\})\\
&=& \frac{\mathsf{P}\left(X_n=z_n\mid X_{n-1}=z_{n-1}\right)\sum_{\mathbf{z}\in S^{n-k}}\mathsf{P}\left(A\cap\{\mathbf{X} = \mathbf{z}\}\right)}{\mathsf{P}\left(\cup_{\mathbf{z}\in S^{n-k}}A\cap\{\mathbf{X} = \mathbf{z}\}\right)}.
\end{eqnarray}

Finally, note that
\begin{eqnarray}
&& \sum_{\mathbf{z}\in S^{n-k}}\mathsf{P}\left(A\cap\{\mathbf{X} = \mathbf{z}\}\right)\\
&=& \mathsf{P}\left(\cup_{\mathbf{z}\in S^{n-k}}A\cap\{\mathbf{X} = \mathbf{z}\}\right).
\end{eqnarray}

We have arrived at
\begin{eqnarray}
&& \mathsf{P}(X_n = z_n\mid \overbrace{X_{n-1}=z_{n-1},\ldots,X_{n-k}=z_{n-k}}^{A})\\
&=& \mathsf{P}(X_n = z_n\mid A)\\
&=& \mathsf{P}(X_n = z_n\mid A\cap\underbrace{\{\mathbf{X}\in S^{n-k}}_{\Omega}\})\\
&=& \mathsf{P}(X_n = z_n\mid X_{n-1} = z_{n-1})\times\frac{\sum_{\mathbf{z}\in S^{n-k}}\mathsf{P}\left(A\cap\{\mathbf{X} = \mathbf{z}\}\right)}{\mathsf{P}\left(\cup_{\mathbf{z}\in S^{n-k}}A\cap\{\mathbf{X} = \mathbf{z}\}\right)}\\
&=& \mathsf{P}(X_n = z_n\mid X_{n-1} = z_{n-1}).
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could you explain how you get the line after "Then the probability in the final line can be expressed as"? I don't see that. Does it hold that $P(A | B, C) = P(A | B)P(C)$ (for all events $A, B, C$)? I only know this very general formula without this $B$.

Comment: @s-m-roch: I have edited the proof. It is longer but clearer now.

Comment: @s-m-roch: Let $B_i$ be disjoint events and $B=\cup_i B_i$. Then $P(A|B) = P(A\cap B)/P(B) = P(A\cap(\cup_i B_i))/P(B) = P(\cup_i (A\cap B_i))P(B) = \sum_i P(A\cap B_i)/P(B) = \sum_i P(A|B_i)P(B_i)/P(B)$

Comment: @s-m-roch: Now suppose $\cup_i B_i = B = \Omega$. Then $P(B)=P(\Omega) = 1$, and $P(A|B) = \sum_i P(A|B_i)P(B_i)/P(B) = \sum_i P(A|B_i)P(B_i)$